# c# / More effective way to upload file with ftp

Tags: c#, ftp, timeout

I'm uploading a .txt file with c# and:

`client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpU, ftpP);
client.UploadFile("here ftp server", "STOR", lfilepath);`

And sometimes it just throws error like "System Error"

This .txt is just log in information, content of this txt is like `User: Name At: 2015/12/12 08:43 AM`

Is there any option to eliminate this error? Make ftp upload more effective? Or any idea to save log on informations in Internet.

Comment: implement try..catch(Exception ex) and edit your post with real message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ***FtpWebRequest*** and ***WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile***. Here is the piece of code which we use for uplaoding files from ZipArchive to FTP (so there is also an option showing creating a directories if you need it too). From all methods which I've tested it was the most efficient one.

```
//// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
var request =
    (FtpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ftpServer + @"/" + remotePath + @"/" +
                          entry.FullName.TrimEnd('/'));

//// Determine if we are transferring file or directory
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entry.Name) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entry.FullName))
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
else
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

//// Try to transfer file
try
{
    //// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);

    switch (request.Method)
    {
        case WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory:
            break;

        case WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile:
            var buffer = new byte[8192];
            using (var rs = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                StreamUtils.Copy(entry.Open(), rs, buffer);
            }

            break;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //// Handle it!
    LogHelper.Error<FtpHelper>("Could not extract file from package.", ex);
}
finally
{
    //// Get the response from the FTP server.
    var response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    //// Close the connection = Happy a FTP server.
    response.Close();
}
```